# MS Access -Continuous form breaks when open via switchboard

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a continuous form that works when I manually open it. However when I open it via a switchboard button, the form loads, but no data (in the detail section) appears. What could be causing this problem? I had this issue once before, but I forget how I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you selected "Open Form in Add Mode" from the "Command" combo for that Switchboard item, the form will not display existing data.  The consequence is similar to setting `Data Entry = Yes` on the Data tab of the form's property sheet, or opening the form from VBA like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "YourFormName", DataMode:=acFormAdd
```